# How to detect USB data polarity?

Tags: usb, usb-device, polarity

Assuming we have a USB (1.x or 2.0) device and know what pins are for `+5` and `GND`, is there a general way to detect which of the other pins is for `data+` and which for `data-`?

There's no old schema so I can't make it live then measure/oscilloscope the real signal.

Also, how danger it is to swap `data+` and `data-`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no danger in swapping D+ with D-. If the connection is done wrong, the interface will just fail. If fails, just swap the wires and try again.

The initial bus state is one of wires pulled up (nominal 1.5k to 3.3v). If the pull-up is on D+ wire (as host sees it), the device is FS (or HS) capable. The host will assert "USB_reset" (drive both lines with 45 Ohms to ground), and start "idle" traffic of SOFs (Start-Of-Frames) with proper signal rate (and amplitude).

If the pull-up is on D- (as host senses it), the host will assume the device is LS, and will invoke proper LS signaling.

If the wires are swapped by mistake, the host will engage into wrong interface (relative to the device side). With wrong wire polarity the device will simply not understand the traffic and will simply fail to respond. You will see "unknown device', or "enumeration fail", or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The idle state of a USB (depending on LS or FS) is for one of the D+ and D- lines to be high (pulled up to 3.3V) so you can't really tell from a quick meter check.  However there is *no* danger in swapping D+ and D-; the host will simply fail to enumerate the device if the lines are swapped.

If you want something more sophisticated, you can monitor the waveforms on these lines and determine which is which. Note that USB 1 FS and LS "connect" sequences are different, and both are different from a USB 2.0 chirp sequence which signals a connection. I don't know how deep down the rabbit hole you want to go, but the USB spec is probably a good place to start if you want something more involved than a quick check.

Answer (score 0):

The device side should have a 1.5k resistor between +3.3V and one of the data pins, usually D+, to indicate the device is full speed capable. True low speed devices have become seldom, so while that isn't infallible, it's a good hint.

On the host side, if you are running Linux, you can use the same thing to test: just pull one data lane up to +3.3V via a 1.5k resistor and check the system log, it should say whether a "low speed" or "full speed" device failed to enumerate.

Wikipedia has a good table on [USB symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_(Communications)#Line_state_(covering_USB_1.x_and_2.x)).